# Retrive objects with the same id in json array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to retrive objects with the same id in my json array made with javascript

```
var Array = {               
    "1": {"text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"},
    "1": {"text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},
    "1": {"text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"},
    "2": {"text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"},
};
```

I tried in this way, but obviously it shows me only the first result (Number one)

```
var get = Array[1]; 
alert(get.text);
```

I thought about a loop, What can I do?

Comment: An ID (or key) by nature should be unique, that's what it does, it **identifies** something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Do not use `Array` as a variable name.
- Object keys cannot be duplicate. If you do, only the latest entry is fed to that key. The others are discarded. In your case, only the third "1" is accessible via the "1" key.
- **What you need is an array**, not an object

You need this:

```
var myArray = [               
    {"id" : 1, "text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"},    //index 0
    {"id" : 1, "text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},    //index 1
    {"id" : 1, "text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"},  //index 2
    {"id" : 2, "text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"}     //index 3
];

var i;

for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
  if(myArray[i].id === 1){
    console.log(myArray[i].text);
  }
}
```

---

Here's another approach, and this requires restructuring your data. If your entry with id of 1 has multiple values, you could hold an array under each key.

```
var myArray = {               
  "1" : [
    {"text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"},  //index 0
    {"text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},  //index 1
    {"text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"} //index 2
  ],
  "2" : [
    {"text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"}   //index 0
  ]
};

var ones = myArray['1'];

for(i=0;i<ones.length;i++){
  console.log(ones[i].text);
}
```

---

Another approach is the use of [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var myArray = [               
  {"id" : 1, "text": "Number one", "time": "16 03 13"},    //index 0
  {"id" : 1, "text": "Number two", "time": "14 03 13"},    //index 1
  {"id" : 1, "text": "Number three", "time": "13 03 13"},  //index 2
  {"id" : 2, "text": "Number one", "time": "13 03 13"}     //index 3
];

//create an array containing only those with id of 1
var filtered = myArray.filter(function(val,i,arr){
  return val.id === 1;
});

for(i=0;i<filtered.length;i++){
  console.log(filtered[i].text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply, but in this way, I can't get any id.
For example, if I would like to get only the texts with the ID 1?

Comment: Is there any simple way to do this?
     `{"text": "Number one", "id": "1"},    
    {"text": "Number two", "id": "1"},    
    {"text": "Number three", "id": "1"},  
    {"text": "Number one", "id": "2"}`
Can I show only the id 1 in this way?

Comment: @Alberto updated. each gets the corresponding text of an entry.

Comment: A lot of ways, thanks for examples, that's really kind of you ...
Now I know how to show one array value, but how I can show **every** "text" with id 1? Not only the first or the second; each text with id 1.

Comment: @Alberto with any of those stated above, you can do a loop.

Comment: Yes, this is the true problem, the loop, how I can do this in a simple way?

Comment: @Alberto added loops for each.